# Why am I being told I can't use my iPod when I clearly am?

Tags: technical-issues, ps4

I have an old 80GB iPod which is used as a harddrive because the screen's been smashed. I generally use it to put movies on there and watch them on my PS3.

Recently I learned that the files were just as compatible on the PS4 and it's a hell of a lot easier to keep track when watching long series thank to the Recently Viewed list.

However when I plug up my iPod into my PS4 I get a message saying that the device can't be used. But it clearly can evident by the fact that I have been watching videos off it and transfer images from the capture gallery to it.

Why am I being told I can't use my iPod when I clearly am? is there some sort of functionality that I'm not aware of that I can't use with my iPod but can with another device?

NOTE: not sure what generation the iPod is but it looks like an [iPod Classic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPod_Classic)

Comment: What generation iPod is it?

Comment: @TimmyJim not sure but it's one of the ones which had that button ring where you circle your finger in the ring to scroll. at best it looks like a [IPod Classic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPod_Classic)

Comment: Have you re-formatted your iPod to use it as external storage? If so this could be a formatting issue, PS4 can only read Fat32 or ExFat formatted drives. Could you have formatted the iPod to NTFS? Edit: I think iPods are Fat32 by default.

Comment: @Colin the ps3 would not be able to read NTFS either

Comment: If I remember correctly Apple didn't want people playing media on iPods  that wasn't copied there by iTunes so did something to prevent that. Your PS4 may be warning you that you wouldn't be able to use the iPod play any songs or other media copied from from the PS4 to the iPod.

Comment: @Colin the iPod is FAT32. i think you may have misunderstood something in the question, i am getting the notice about the device not being usable despite the fact that said device is working on the PS4 so i am wondering why i am being told it's not usable

Answer (score 1):

So your problem is just the error message?

This [thread](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/691087-playstation-4/72046404) seems to state that only USB HDDs can be used:

> I think it only works with straight USB flash drives. If you are using an external HDD as a main storage unit, I'm not sure it will work. One of the reasons is the PS4 is only going to recognize USB drives up to a certain storage max.

Perhaps this is why you are getting the error message.

You could get rid of those error messages if you connect the ipod to a computer running a media server, and then connect from the ps4, as outlined in this [article](http://onebestsoft.com/play-movies-on-ps4-from-usb/)

Comment: Sort of seems ridiculous to do so though...